# union of two default dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, defaultdict, set-union

am trying to create a union of two default dictionaries. Here is the code for the method in my class:

```
def __add__(self,right):
    mergedbag = copy.copy(self.bag_value)
    for item in right:
        if item not in mergedbag:mergedbag[item] = 0
        mergedbag[item] += right[item]
    return mergedbag
```

I create two default dictionaries:

```
b = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
c = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
```

the result of

```
print(b+c)
```

should be the total count of elements after the union..

```
Bag(a[a],b[4],c[3],d[6])
```

This is the error I keep getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\workspace33\courselib\driver.py", line 229, in driver

Command[print(b+c)]:     exec(old,local,globl)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\workspace33\Project2\src\bag.py", line 58, in __add__
    mergedbag[item] += right[item]
TypeError: 'Bag' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the new code:

```
class Bag:
def __init__(self, items = []):
    self.bag_value = defaultdict(int)
    for item in items:
        self.bag_value[item] += 1


def __repr__(self):
    bag_list = []
    for item, count in self.bag_value.items():
        bag_list.extend(list(item*count))
    return 'Bag(' + str(bag_list) + ')'



def __str__(self):
    return 'Bag(' + ','.join(str(item) + '[' + str(count) + ']' for item, count in self.bag_value.items()) + ')'



def __len__(self):
    bag_len = 0
    for value in self.bag_value:
        bag_len += self.bag_value[value]
    return bag_len



def unique(self):
    return len(self.bag_value)




def __contains__(self, item):
    return item in self.bag_value



def count(self, item):
    return(self.bag_items.count(item))



def add(self, new):
    self.bag_value[new] += 1



def __add__(self,right):
    mergedbag = copy.copy(self.bag_value)
    for item in right:
        if item not in mergedbag:mergedbag[item] = 0
        mergedbag[item] += right[item]
    return mergedbag



def remove(self, item):
    if item in self.bag_items:
        del(item)
    else:
        raise ValueError(type_as_str(item) + ' not in bag.')



def __eq__(self, right):
    if type(right) is not Bag:
        raise TypeError('Cannot compare Bag with' + type_as_str(right) + '. Can only compare Bag with Bag')
    else:
        return (len(self) == len(right)) and  (self.unique() == right.unique())



def __ne__(self, right):
    return not self.__eq__(right)



def _bag_gen(self, bag_value):
    for item in self.bag_value:
        for count in range(self.bag_value[item]):
            yield item



def __iter__(self):
    return self._bag_gen(self.bag_value)



if __name__ == '__main__':
#     bag = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
#     bag2 = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
#     bag3 = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b'])
#     print(bag == bag2)
#     print(bag == bag3)
#     print(bag != bag2)
#     print(bag != bag3)
    import driver
    driver.driver()
```

Comment: What is `Bag` and what do you mean by `Is there a way to make the method accept command str(Bag(['a','b] + Bag(['b','c']))`?

Comment: `Bag['a', 'b]` is missing a `'` - `Bag['a', 'b']`. If there is still an error after that, it would help if you could post the full traceback as well as more of your `Bag` class.

Comment: @Ivc - just posted the class

Comment: We also need to see the *exact* error you're getting, not just "there's a syntax error".

Comment: I have several recommendations about this code: 1. I would tend to inherit bag from defaultdict(int), so you don't have to implement many methods as len(). 2. Try to use more iteritems() instead of items(). 3. Try to avoid defaulting parameters to objects like items=[], as those objects are reused among function calls. Not sure if a problem here, but  I would recommend to use items=None

Comment: @drodri- the other methods are independent and are used for testing other stuff like length of a bag, unique items in a bag and so on.

Comment: Which points to exactly the missing quote I suggested in my first comment. Fixing that should fix the immediate problem.. voting to close as typo.

Comment: @drodri the question is tagged [python-3.x], where `dict.items` no longer creates a list. Also, you can't inherit `defaultdict(it)`, only `defaultdict`.. But you can get the same effect by inheriting dict and defining `__missing__` to return 0, which is what `collections.Counter` does.

Comment: @drodri, Ivc..I've updated the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ups, sorry about 3.x, didnt see it. I know that other methods are auxiliary, but it helps to strip them out and leave it to the bare minimum to reproduce the issue. I still see some problems: __ init __ receives items that are actually not assigned to bag_items (is this something special of 3.x?). The method __ add __ still receives 2 parameters, as @st0le says, the signature should be __ add __(self, other), it is not fixed yet.

Comment: @drodri - I've made changes to the `__init__` as well to do the assignment to the bag_items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is important to note that your Bag class is basically the same as a Counter. If you need any specific extension, just inherit from it and you are done. I would say that the following code just address all the functionality you are implementing yourself in your Bag class:

```
from collections import Counter

class Bag(Counter):
    pass

b = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])
c = Bag(['d','a','b','d','c','b','d'])

print (b)
print (c)
print (b+c)
```

If you are doing an exercise to learn, the problem is that you are not implementing **setitem** and **getitem** methods in your Bag class to allow the [] notation. You could implement them or just access the attribute bag_value:

```
def __add__(self, right):
    mergedbag = Bag()
    mergedbag.bag_value = copy.copy(self.bag_value)
    for item in right.bag_value.keys():
        mergedbag.bag_value[item] += right.bag_value[item]
    return mergedbag
```

Be sure to create and return a Bag object

Answer (score 0):

The definition is

`def __add__(self,other):`

So you ought to merge the contents of `self.items` with `other.items` and then return the result.

Also, not sure if `bag1+bag2` will work, but my pyfu is weak, you will explicitly have to iterate through them and add the counts together.

```
import copy

c = {'a':2,'b':1}
d = {'b':1,'c':1}

#
mergedBag = copy.copy(c) #might wanna use deepcopy?
for k in d:
    if k not in mergedBag: mergedBag[k] = 0
    mergedBag[k] += d[k]

print mergedBag
```

Comment: @st0le..I've updated the question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @BoJaNgLeS, Hi, As explained in my answer `dict1+dict2` won't work. You'll have to iterate over each key and create a new merged dict. I've added some code above.

Comment: @st0le- I tried that and it gives me a object not subscriptable error. I've updated the code.